# 'ERROR: transport error 202: recv error: Connection reset by peer' while debugging Maven Project in vscode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, debugging, multi-module

**Environment:**

- VS Code Version: 1.73.1
- Extension Version: Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat v1.13.2022111603
- JDK Type & Version: Oracle jdk1.8.0_351 - 32bit
- OS Type & Version: Windows 10 Enterprise

**Step to Reproduce:**

- Open an existing multi-module maven project in VS Code and wait until it is fully loaded. This project is relatively huge.
- Setup `launch.json` with `attach` and `launch` for Java Project
- The `launch` config is working fine. Still, after a couple of minutes, I get `ERROR: transport error 202: recv error: Connection reset by peer` in the terminal, and the debugger is disconnected.
- The same happens with the `attach` config.
- I am able to debug successfully as long as the debugger is not disconnected.
- When debugging in the `attach` config, the debugger keeps on listening, and I can attach again, but it will disconnect after a couple of minutes.
- Even after the debugger is disconnected, the application is still active.
- The command used to start the debugger in `attach` mode is:

```
C:\apps\jdk1.8.0_351\bin\java.exe "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:60082" '-Xincgc -Xms64m -Xmx950m' '-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation="true"' '-Djava.security.policy="policy.all"' '-Dpython.home=".."' '-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings="false"' '-Xbootclasspath/p:class1 class2 ...' '-cp' '.\classpath.jar' 'mainClassName'
```

Note: The command above to start the debugger is provided by copying parts of the output from the terminal which is based on the actual command used to launch the actual application.

Launch Config for the `attach request`:

```
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Attach to java debug port 60082",
            "projectName": "sarora",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "localhost",
            "port": "60082"
        }
```

**Expected Behavior:**

- The debugger should remain active and should not disconnect

**Actual Behavior:**

- The debugger disconnects after a couple of minutes.

**Related Issues:** 
I found this report to be similar:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/164
and I followed the instructions to do the needed troubleshooting but it is not working.

Comment: What options did you modify? Are you having trouble running the code? How do you debug code? See [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_run-and-debug) for an introduction to debugging.

Comment: I can run the code and I can start the debugger and all is OK. The only problem is that the debugger will disconnect after a couple of minutes as mentioned in the post above.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your problem here. If you have enough information, you can file a report on GitHub.

Comment: It's already reported on GitHub.